# Git error 128 adding react-navigation/bottom-tabs

Tags: react-native, github, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

While I'm trying to do 'yarn add react-navigation/bottom-tabs' terminal show me the error:

error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/react-navigation/bottom-tabs.git
Directory: /Users/adrianzakrzewski/Documents/Uczelnia/INŻYNIERKA/StudyNote
Output:
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

This is my package.json file:

"name": "studynote",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
"@react-navigation/native": "react-navigation/native",
"expo": "~50.0.6",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
"npm": "^10.4.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.4",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
"yarn": "^1.22.21"

},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
},
"private": true

- Yesterday I generated a SSH key and added to my GitHub account.
- I have deleted npm config registry and updated it
- I have updated npm to latest

Nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yarn add @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
```

Try to add a **@**

Comment: Thank you very much, it works finally <3

One question, why when I add react-navigation/native I don't need to use @ but to add bottom-tabs here is needed?

Comment: Well in the docs they say that you have to add it this way
yarn add @react-navigation/native.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Comment: Oh yes, it's true. I was watching this docs but I didn't think about using @. Thank you again.